# Permission denied (publickey,password) in Debian

Tags: linux, ssh, permissions

I am working on Linux. I flash the emmc with the help of SDCard... The flashing is done successfully. After that, I opened the minicom and I am able to login but when I am trying with Linux terminal with the command

```
ssh debian@192.168.7.2
```

getting error

> Permission denied, please try again

Can someone please help me to solve this problem?

Thank you